# Requiring to assert a[0] in a

Tags: dafny

I'm currently learning dafny and ran into a really odd assertion requirement:

```
method M (a : seq<int>, acc : seq<int>) 
  requires |a| > 0
  requires forall va, vacc :: va in a && vacc in acc ==> vacc <= va
{
  assert forall vacc :: vacc in acc ==> vacc <= a[0];
}
```

The above code fails on the assertion, however if I add `assert a[0] in a` it verifies?

Why is this the case, surely in all circumstances that `|a| > 0` `a[0] in a` holds since `seq` is immutable?

(also any style guide recommendations would be appreciated :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with "triggers".

The short answer is that until you manually "mention" `a[0]`, Dafny will not be able to take advantage of the quantified `requires` clause. It does not matter *how* you mention `a[0]`, just that you mention it. That is why your trivial assertion works even though it doesn't seem to add anything logically: it's just because it mentions `a[0]`.

For more information, see:

- the [FAQ qustion](https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/wiki/FAQ#how-does-dafny-handle-quantifiers-ive-heard-about-triggers-what-are-those)
- [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50668693/what-are-triggers-in-dafny-boogie/50671326#50671326) "what are triggers?"
- [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49398650/dafny-what-does-no-terms-found-to-trigger-on-mean/49399562#49399562) about "no terms found to trigger on"

Comment: Brilliant thanks! Are there any good herustics for when this may be an issue?

Comment: It will basically always be an issue whenever you have a `forall` fact that you need to take advantage of. It also happens any time you're trying to *prove* an `exists` fact.